# Question answered and works, but not voted or accepted as answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, up-votes

I have seen many posts in which the question was answered and the person who asked the question comments that the answer works perfectly. But they never care for voting up or even accepting it as an answer.

Should we just ignore it and continue our responsibility to help or what has to be done in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this thread on the main Meta site:
[Problem with users not accepting answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119197/problem-with-users-not-accepting-answers)

> Accepting an answer is purely voluntary and there's no obligation to do so.
>
> A lot of us participate here because we want to be helpful. If you're after reputation and green checkmarks, you might find it difficult to deal with the fact that there's nothing we can or should do to force people to vote or accept answers.
>
> We already encourage voting and accepting answers via pop-ups, showing the accept rate on user cards, etc. Beyond that... it's all status-bydesign.